# Grunt Dynamic file mapping with relative destination

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I feel like this should be easy and I'm making it harder than it should be, however Im trying to create minified js files using grunt uglify from multiple folders relative to their source file. So for example:

```
uglify: {
  modules: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: "<%= modules %>",
      src: "**/js/*.js",
      dest: "same folder as source file", <-- this is the part I don't know
      ext: ".min.js",
      extDot: "first"
    }]
  }
}
```

Original Directory Structure:

```
- Modules/
-- Module 1/
--- js/
---- module1script.js
-- Module 2/
--- js/
---- module2script.js
```

After files are minified:

```
- Modules/
-- Module 1/
--- js/
---- module1script.js
---- module1script.min.js
-- Module 2/
--- js/
---- module2script.js
---- module2script.min.js
```

Without having to write a task for each module folder because the modules are dependent upon the project and change frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the `dest` option empty will output the minified files at their relative source path.

The grunt configuration for uglify task would be

```
uglify: {
        modules: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: "Modules/**/js/*.js",
                dest: "",
                ext: ".min.js",
                extDot: "first"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you!!! I just figured it had to be something easy! I tried removing the "dest" all together before, but not just leaving it blank.